# MySQL not using indexes

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

I just enabled the slow-log (+not using indexes) and I'm getting hundreds of entries for the same kind of query (only `user` changes)

```
SELECT id
     , name 
  FROM `all` 
 WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id 
                   FROM `picks` 
                  WHERE user=999) 
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

EXPLAIN gives:

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------+------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table             | type  | possible_keys    | key    | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                                    |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------+------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | all               | index | NULL             | name   | 156     | NULL       |  209 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort | 
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | picks             | ref   | user,user_2,pick | user_2 | 8       | const,func |    1 | Using where; Using index                 | 
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------+------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

Any idea about how to optimize this query? I've tried with a bunch of different indexes on different fields but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't necessarily agree that 'not in' and 'exists' are ALWAYS bad performance choices, however, it could be in this situation.

You might be able to get your results using a much simpler query:

```
SELECT id
     , name 
  FROM `all`
     , 'picks'
 WHERE all.id = picks.id
   AND picks.user <> 999 
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: That will get all picks belonging to any user except the 999 one, right? What the query does (but not in an efficient way) is getting the list of 'available' picks but removing the ones already picked by the user.

Comment: This query wouldn't return anything for rows that don't have a matching entry in `picks`, while the original query would.

Comment: simple enough fix, just outer join it.

Comment: I'm thinking on doing this on the software side. The same subquery is used a few lines after this one, and may be a good idea to perform the discard-if-exists in memory.

Comment: How are you going to do a "not in" subquery in memory without selecting *all* rows? That's going to be slower than the sequential scan on the DB server. Seriously, just create an index on picks (id, user) and use the left join query.

Comment: In fact, I was just thinking about putting the pick.id in an array and looping about every match of the DB, then omitting the ones present in the array. I also use pick.id later, so it's not a problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

"not in" and "exists" always bad choices for performance. May be left join with cheking "NULL" will be better try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best way to write the query. Select everything from `all` and try to find matching rows from `picks` that share the same `id` and `user` is `999`. If such a row doesn't exist, `picks.id` will be `NULL`, because it's using a left outer join. Then you can filter the results to return only those rows.

```
SELECT all.id, all.name 
FROM
    all
    LEFT JOIN picks ON picks.id=all.id AND picks.user=999
WHERE picks.id IS NULL
ORDER BY all.name ASC
```